# Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [appcenterdb-oracle] failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed the following on my RHEL 6 
(1)  MFP63 
(2)  MySQL56
(3)  WAS 8.5.5.6

and trying to set up my first mobile first project but 'messages.log' has the following errors

```
I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.WAS-v20150513-26196d2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [appcenterdb-oracle] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7157] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.WAS-v20150513-26196d2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.PushBatchDeviceEntity] must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column to map its relationship attribute [device]. com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory 759" at ffdc_15.07.27_21.00.27.0.log
[7/27/15 21:00:27:238 IST] 00000068 com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo                       E CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the appcenterdb-oracle persistence unit. The following error occurred: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.WAS-v20150513-26196d2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [appcenterdb-oracle] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7157] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.WAS-v20150513-26196d2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.PushBatchDeviceEntity] must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column to map its relationship attribute [device].
```

Message says 'Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [appcenterdb-oracle] failed' but I am using 'MySQL' instead of 'oracle' which is bit confusing to me

I  am using Java 8 (with JDK6 and 7 I was facing other issues)

http://pastebin.com/WcWBUjVn  (server.xml)
http://pastebin.com/QzByZ63T  (messages.log)

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Comment: MobileFirst does not support Java 8. First downgrade.

Comment: Thanks Idan.  I downgraded but now I face "[7/28/15 0:38:33:099 IST] 00000064 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              E SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [AuthorizationServer] in application [worklightconsole]: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.worklight.oauth.AuthorizationServerApplication cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Application" followed by 'Timeout error - 120 secs'

Is MFP63 and WAS8556 a good combination?

Comment: WAS 8.5.5.6 was not tested with MFPF 6.3; you can try 8.5.5.5.

Comment: @Idan, no matter what version of WAS and Java I try I always get 'Timeout error'.  However, once thing what I noticed in 'messages.log' is it prints the message 'Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST' several times and then it 'TIMES OUT'.  I guess either something should be wrong with MySQL or with server.xml.  Your thoughts please

Comment: Update the messages.log and server.xml links. I don't see any timeout.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BCMsG2Zz  (server.xml)
http://pastebin.com/4HjCrhZ0 ( messages.log)  error message can be seen at the end.  But I doubt entries of 'WL admin service' and 'WL runtime' in server.xml but not sure as I am very new to Mobile

Comment: Hello All,  I upgraded to MFP7 and using MySQL 56 and now I hit with the following error 'Could not find required filter class - com.worklight.core.auth.impl.OAuthServletFilter.class'.        I could not find the 'class' in worklight-jee*.jar.   Is it possible to include this 'class' definition or can I 'disable OAuthFilter' for my WAS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues in total:

1. You are using Java 8 with a MobileFirst Foundation version that does not support it. The [system requirements of MobileFirst Foundation 7.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/r_supported_operating_systems_an.html) state that only Java 6 and Java 7 are supported. The symptom is seen in your first messages.log: It is the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher`
2. Your server.xml contains two elements `<application id="worklightconsole" name="worklightconsole" location="worklightconsole.war" type="war">`. That is, you have two web applications with the same id, the same name, and the same context root. This can never work. The cause is apparently that you passed worklightconsole.war as argument to <configureApplicationServer>. Instead, as documented in [Deploying the project WAR file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html), the WAR file that you specify should be a MobileFirst project WAR file, built through MobileFirst Studio or through the <war-builder> Ant task.
3. The second messages.log file contains the log messages

   ```
   FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin,qualifier=worklightadmin
   FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=ProjectManagement_simpleServer,qualifier=worklightconsole [project worklightconsole]
   ```

   The first one shows an empty environment id, whereas the second one shows an environment id "simpleServer". This environment id is also visible in the server.xml file:

   ```
   <jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"simpleServer"'/>
   ```

   But according to the [documentation of <configureApplicationServer>](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.reference.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_configure_appserver_reference.html), you should pass the same environment id value in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
@slowhand   For 'Point #2' can you mention the line no's so that I can understand as I am really new to mobile
And 'For Point #4'  I really did not get 'same environment id value in both cases' though I have seen this in many blogs.    What 'tags'  and 'line #' you are referring to.  And more importantly 'which value of the tag should match with which tag'?

Comment: @Olivier.  Unfortunately the image wlp-core-runtime-8.5.5.6 does not exists on fix central

Comment: JAR Install: WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core V8.5.5.6 Runtime
wlp-core-runtime-8.5.5.6.jar (58.86 MB)

Comment: @Sathish, I have just checked on FixCentral and I confirm I can see the jar file :
JAR Install: WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core V8.5.5.6 Runtime : wlp-core-runtime-8.5.5.6.jar (58.86 MB).
In my procedure, instead of 
Individual fix IDs : wlp-core-runtime-8.5.5.6
try selecting Browse for fixes, you should get many more results but the jar should be in the list. There are many pages, make sure to press hyperlink All to get all the pages before searching the result page for this jar.

Answer (score 1):

@Sathish, In the server.xml you have uploaded, I can see those features

```
<feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
  <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
  <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
```

The last two features are not installed by MobileFirst Ant tasks or the Server Configuration Tool.
This let me think you changed them manually after the installation process because you are using an unsupported Liberty profile flavour like
  *WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 with Java EE 7 Web Profile* or *WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 with Java EE 7 Full Platform*
which does not provide the expected features servlet-3.0 and jdbc-4.0 but instead servlet-3.1 and jdbc-4.1.

Actually, MFP 6.3 only supports MFP 6.3 only supports WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core 
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=1404132386734#!
which contains

You may get it from the FixCentral website
http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/

On Select product tab, choose
Product Group : WebSphere
Select from WebSphere : WebSphere Application Server
Installed Version : 8.5.5.6
Platform : All
Then select
Individual fix IDs : wlp-core-runtime-8.5.5.6

Answer (score 0):

As 'slowhand' suggested the issue was with 'server.xml' because of multiple 'application id' with the same name

It appears 'ant' tasks does not generate all the tags correctly and I made little corrections to make it work

Thanks
Sathish Kumar